# Как отделить написанные латиницей мужские имена от женских?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Как разделить мужские имена от женских написанные на латинском алфавите?
Пример:

```
names = 
["Sasha","Alice","Valeriy","Jenny","Fedya","Viola","Mark","Chris","Margo"]
```

Answer (score 4):

Воспользуемся бесплатным сервисом [genderize.io](https://genderize.io) распознавания пола по имени, также установим `requests` через `python -m pip install requests`.

[Попробовать код онлайн!](https://replit.com/@moytrage/RuStackOverflow1410948#main.py)

```py
import requests

def detect_gender(name):
    return requests.get('https://api.genderize.io', params = {'name': name}).json()

names = ["Sasha","Alice","Valeriy","Jenny","Fedya","Viola","Mark","Chris","Margo"]

for name in names:
    res = detect_gender(name)
    print(name, ',', res['gender'], res)
```

Вывод:

```
Sasha , male {'name': 'Sasha', 'gender': 'male', 'probability': 0.51, 'count': 13219}
Alice , female {'name': 'Alice', 'gender': 'female', 'probability': 0.98, 'count': 68971}
Valeriy , male {'name': 'Valeriy', 'gender': 'male', 'probability': 0.98, 'count': 1155}
Jenny , female {'name': 'Jenny', 'gender': 'female', 'probability': 0.98, 'count': 74278}
Fedya , male {'name': 'Fedya', 'gender': 'male', 'probability': 0.91, 'count': 155}
Viola , female {'name': 'Viola', 'gender': 'female', 'probability': 0.99, 'count': 29324}
Mark , male {'name': 'Mark', 'gender': 'male', 'probability': 0.99, 'count': 119313}
Chris , male {'name': 'Chris', 'gender': 'male', 'probability': 0.9, 'count': 156083}
Margo , female {'name': 'Margo', 'gender': 'female', 'probability': 0.95, 'count': 3485}
```

---

Также можно за один раз запросить до 10 имён, как сделано в коде ниже, чтобы снизить задержки от сервера и нагрузку.

[Попробовать код онлайн!](https://replit.com/@moytrage/RuStackOverflow1410948var2#main.py)

```py
import requests

def detect_gender(names):
    return requests.get('https://api.genderize.io',
        params = tuple(('name[]', n) for n in names)).json()

names = ["Sasha","Alice","Valeriy","Jenny","Fedya","Viola","Mark","Chris","Margo"]

for i in range(0, len(names), 10):
    ns = names[i : i + 10]
    for name, res in zip(ns, detect_gender(ns)):
        print(name, ',', res['gender'], res)
```

Вывод тот же, что и в предыдущем коде.

---

**PS**. [genderize.io](https://genderize.io/) бесплатно предоставляет квоту до 1000 запрошенных имён в день, думаю больше лимит доступен после регистрации, и если очень много надо, то только платно.

Comment: Хорошо, 
А что означает  'probability': 0.51, 'count': 13219 ?

Comment: @Coder `probability` это точно значит Вероятность, т.е. 0.98 вероятность например значит что на 98% уверены что это мужское имя например. Видно в выводе выше что Sasha на 51% уверено мужское, т.к. оно бывает и женским. А вот `count` точно не знаю, дословно это означает `количество`, предполагаю что это значит что была взята по всем странам база данных реальных людей, например 100 000 000 людей, и среди этого количества людей такое то `count` количество содержит данное имя, скорее всего так. Другими словами чем `count` больше тем имя популярней.

Comment: @Coder Только что добавил вторую часть ответа, где показал как делать запрос на множество имён за один раз. Также прочитайте добавленный в конце **PS**, где говорится что бесплатная квота сервера до 1000 имён в день.

Comment: Классное решение, но для списка имен можно не заморачиваться с конкатенацией параметров.  `response = requests.get('https://api.genderize.io', params=(('name', 'lois'),('name', 'stevie')))` вот так тоже параметры можно указывать

Comment: @Namerek Забыл, спасибо! Действительно давно когда то я в `requests` использовал `params` возможность, просто про неё забыл и сделал вручную.

Comment: Норм, я ее просто каждый день мучаю в разных позициях, не хочешь - запомнишь. Просто в данном случае пораметры не ввиде словаря а ввиде кортежа кортежей коскольку словарь не схавает одинаковые названия параметров. Добавьте в ответ, думаю будет лучше.

Comment: @Namerek Только что добавил в мой ответ в оба кода использование `params = ...` параметров. Спасибо за подсказку!

Answer (score 3):

Ну вот я нагуглил за 10 секунд такой пакет для питона, возможно, вам этого будет достаточно:

```py
# pip install gender-guesser
import gender_guesser.detector as gender

d = gender.Detector()

names = ["Sasha","Alice","Valeriy","Jenny","Fedya","Viola","Mark","Chris","Margo"]
for name in names:
    print(f'{name}: {d.get_gender(name)}')
```

Вывод:

```
Sasha: mostly_male
Alice: female
Valeriy: male
Jenny: female
Fedya: unknown
Viola: female
Mark: male
Chris: mostly_male
Margo: female
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!